# Time complexity related to subArray problem

Tags: time-complexity, sub-array

How we can decrees time complexity of finding subarray of a given array in **O(n) from O(n^3)**

```
void subArray(int arr[],int n) 
{
    int i=0,j,k;
    while(i<n)
    {
        j=i;
        while(j<n)
        {
            k=i;
            while(k<=j)
            {
                cout<<arr[k]<<" ";
                k++;
            }
            cout<<endl;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your `O(N³)` code first.  What do you mean by "find a subArray"

Comment: Also, edit your original question to include your code. Don't put it in the comments.

Comment: Why not use for loops rather than while loops?  `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = i; j < n; j++) { for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) { cout << arr[k] << " "; } cout << endl; } }`

Comment: after using for loop it also O(n^3)

Comment: Oh, definitely not going to change performance, but cleaner code is easier to reason about.

Comment: What is this computing? Can you provide sample input (is this C?) in source code? And the expected output?

Comment: int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
     subArray(arr,5);
    return 0;
}

Comment: You print all the subarrays. You cannot do that in less than O(N^3) time because that's the size of the output. "Finding subarray" doesn't sound the same as "printing all subarrays" to me. Perhaps you want to find some specific subarray (one out of many) but you don't specify which one.

Comment: @VinayYadav - Is that an answer to my question? I don't understand. Please edit your question.